# Automatically free user data in Mat. Is it possible?

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I'm creating a Mat instance with data, which I get from separate file. By doing so, I lose advantage of automatic memory management:

```
char* data = new char[dataLength];
readLength = stream.readRawData(data, dataLength);
Mat image( heigth, width, CV_16U, data );
```

Docs say that I have to free this memory myself.

```
delete[] data;
```

What I want is memory to be released once Mat instance goes out of scope. As if I created Mat with imread function.

Docs offer the use of Ptr<> template class as a smart pointer.(http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html) But I don't get it how to use it with array of char.

I think I can write a wrapper for Mat, that will free that memory. But is there any other way?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Yes, this way of using Ptr compiles well, but still everything doesn't work as expected. I thought I didn't use Ptr correctly. Looks like the nature of my problem lies beyond that. Here's my code:

```
Mat readImage() {

...

Ptr<char> data = new char[dataLength];
readLength = stream.readRawData(data, dataLength);
Mat image( heigth, width, CV_16U, data );
return image;}
```

Could this be that my smart pointer is being messed up when the function returns? Is this because Mat is copied when function returns in my code?

UPDATE II:

Actually I wanted data NOT to be released after function returns. I tried this code:

```
Mat readImage() {

...

Ptr<char> data = new char[dataLength];
readLength = stream.readRawData(data, dataLength);
Mat image( heigth, width, CV_16U, data );
data.addref();
return image;}
```

But it proved to be the same as not to use smart pointer at all. Reference counter is not decreased at the death of Mat object as I hoped it would. But I really can do clone() on image to make data use automatic memory management. I get some overhead, but I can live with this. Thanks to sgar91, who mentioned clone() function.

Comment: I think the data is shared between `cv::Ptr<char> data` and `Mat image`. Data is not destroyed until the reference count becomes zero. You are returning the image. Simply returning a Mat would return a shallow copy of `image` and increase its reference count, so `data` will not be deleted. Try returning a deep copy like this: `return image.clone();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documents clearly state how to do use the `Ptr` class for automatic memory management.

Instead of this:

```
char* data = new char[dataLength];
```

You can do this:

```
cv::Ptr<char> data = new char[dataLength];
```

Comment: You could also use 'std::vector<char> data(dataLength);', and use `&data[0]'. Or a std::unique_ptr. Or a boost::scoped_array.

Comment: Yes there are several alternatives for automatic memory management. `cv::Ptr` is equivalent to `std::shared_ptr` of C++ 11.

Comment: yup, which is why i belong in the comments :-P. (but i have to nitpick, std::vector is c++98, and boost::scoped_array is a different library entirely)